# How to install Firefox for Puppeteer?

Tags: firefox, puppeteer

I've been trying to install firefox for puppeteer for a while,
the docs says to run the next command:

```
PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm i puppeteer
```

But I can't understand where to run it?
I've tried

```
npm config set puppeteer_product firefox
```

Which downloads the Nightly package
but then when trying to run puppeteer I get the next error:

```
(node:27840) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not find browser revision 782078. Run "PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox n
pm install" or "PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox yarn install" to download a supported Firefox browser binary.
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I don't know anything about puppeteer but the tag says it's only for Chrome/Chromium

Comment: no @Rob, actually it is possible to use puppeteer with Firefox as well since a while, see: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer

Comment: have you been able to fix it in the meantime @uSEwrasd?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've correctly enabled Firefox for puppeteer with:

either **npm**

```
PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm install puppeteer
```

or **yarn:**

```
PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox yarn add puppeteer
```

Then you need to set the `product` option of [`puppeteer.launch`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-puppeteerlaunchoptions) to `'firefox'`:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ product: 'firefox' })
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this while installing from a frozen lock file? (using yarn)

Comment: @Daniel, honestly I am not aware of any shorthand for your use case. I'd do a `yarn` for the whole yarn.lock file then I'd proceed with `PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox yarn add puppeteer` which is time-consuming I admit. I suggest asking this question with a "yarn" tag on it so some package manager experts can answer this to you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Delete the puppeteer folder from node_modules. This is to force puppeteer to be reinstalled with the firefox binary in step 2.
2. Run the following commands sequentially in Powershell (if you're on Windows):

   set PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox

   npm i puppeteer

If you're using another OS I think the idea is just to set PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox as a global environment variable before reinstalling puppeteer so it knows to download firefox when it installs.